# PL/SQL: Creating objects

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to create a PL/SQL package and have been delivered a sample package but trying to follow it I couldn't create an object

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_PERSONA_SIGNANT AS OBJECT (
    db_id                         NUMBER(6),
    usuaricreacio                 VARCHAR2(20),
    datacreacio                   VARCHAR2(25),
    nom                           VARCHAR2(25),
    signatura                     VARCHAR2(55),
    disponible                    BOOLEAN,);

CREATE OR REPLACE TBL_PERSONA_SIGNANT IS TABLE OF OBJ_PERSONA_SIGNANT;
```

But I'm still getting:

```
Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'OBJ_PERSONA_SIGNANT' must be declared
```

Shouldn't this be enough? I honestly don't get why would I use an object while all this info is already in a table but new job, new rules.

I'm guessing I should initialize it or something but have spent the last hour trying to find out what/how should I do and my google-fu is not as it was :/

Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you define any schema?

Comment: I doubt you could compile the first statement `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_PERSONA_SIGNANT AS OBJECT` successfully. Firstly, there is an extra comma, secondly the datatype `BOOLEAN` in PLSQL

Answer (score 1):

```
disponible                    BOOLEAN,);
```

Here you have an extra `,` at the end
Again Oracle don't have a boolean datatype [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6263249199595)

Change it to

```
disponible                   VARCHAR2(1));
```

Try;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_PERSONA_SIGNANT AS OBJECT (
    db_id                         NUMBER(6),
    usuaricreacio                 VARCHAR2(20),
    datacreacio                   VARCHAR2(25),
    nom                           VARCHAR2(25),
    signatura                     VARCHAR2(55),
    disponible                  VARCHAR2(1)
)
/ 

CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE TBL_PERSONA_SIGNANT AS TABLE OF OBJ_PERSONA_SIGNANT
/
```

**EDIT**

How would I know if is declared on the schema?

Use `ALL_TYPES` view

```
select * from ALL_TYPES
where owner = 'your_schema'
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The comma came because I deleted some fields but I already changed the boolean declaration. How would I know if is declared on the schema? Sorry but it's been like 15 years since I last touched pl/sql :S

Comment: There is typo as you have used sql terminator `;` and multi-line terminator `/` together.

Comment: @Praveen - surely VARCHAR2 for strings. CHAR is just for ANSI compatibility checklists, not for actual use. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:72243456808191

Answer (score 1):

```
--first you need to check in user object of your type is VALID
select * from user_objects where object_type = 'TYPE' and object_name ='YOUR_TYPE_NAME'
--you can check moere details in user_types 
select * from user_types where type_name ='YOUR_TYPE_NAME'

--you will get type defination in follwing way
select text from user_source where name = 'V_TEMP' order by line
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TYPE', 'V_TEMP') FROM DUAL;
```

finaly if you are using developer tool like toad/ plsql developer then open that type in edit mode and try to compile it from tool window.
here you will get exact error and  you can correct it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your **TYPE** creation:

1. A **typo error** in the end due an **extra comma**.
2. `TYPE` **keyword** is missing in second statement.

Resolving the above two issues would let you create the objects:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_PERSONA_SIGNANT AS OBJECT (
  2      db_id                         NUMBER(6),
  3      usuaricreacio                 VARCHAR2(20),
  4      datacreacio                   VARCHAR2(25),
  5      nom                           VARCHAR2(25),
  6      signatura                     VARCHAR2(55),
  7      disponible                    VARCHAR2(1))
  8  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TBL_PERSONA_SIGNANT IS TABLE OF OBJ_PERSONA_SIGNANT
  2  /

Type created.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Hey just made some minor modications  in your code and it works for me. Let me know if this helps.
DROP TYPE OBJ_PERSONA_SIGNANT;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_PERSONA_SIGNANT AS OBJECT (
    db_id                         NUMBER(6),
    usuaricreacio                 VARCHAR2(20),
    datacreacio                   VARCHAR2(25),
    nom                           VARCHAR2(25),
    signatura                     VARCHAR2(55),
    disponible                    VARCHAR2(10) -- ut may contain 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' wich can be manipulated accrordingly
    );

DROP TYPE TBL_PERSONA_SIGNANT;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TBL_PERSONA_SIGNANT IS TABLE OF OBJ_PERSONA_SIGNANT;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let me thank everyone for your input.
You gave me enough information to find the issue on my own.

Since the declaration was properly written (checked by you guys) I realized I wasn't putting this where it should be.

To any pl/sql developer that might find this in the future: objects are not defined inside the package, you have to go to types on the Object Browser and do a "new" from there!

Again, thanks everyone!

Comment: In PL/SQL you need to create RECORD. OBJECT type is created and stored in the database.